# Fast Toffoli Gate Implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

I'm working on a genetic algorithm using toffoli gates for class. I've got the genetic algorithm working, but it's pretty slow.

The evaluation function runs a toffoli gate function ~10,000 times per "organism". With a population of 1,000 its running over 100,000 times per generation. It is by far the slowest part of my genetic algorithm.

For my implementation, a [Toffoli Gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate) acts on a bit string. Each bit has a state of None, On, Off, or Flip. Only one bit per string can have the FLIP state. The toffoli gate flips the bit set to FLIP, if all bits with the state ON are 1, and all bits set to OFF are 0, ignoring the None bits.

For Example

```
X = FLIP
@ = ON
O = OFF
- = NONE
```

Then the input of "1001" and a toffoli gate of "X0-@" would look like

```
1001
XO-@
----
0001
```

What would be a fast way to implement this?

My initial implementation uses bitsets.

```
#define BITLEN 10
#define INPUT std::bitset<BITLEN>
#define GATE std::bitset<BITLEN*2>

void toffoli(const GATE* gate, INPUT* state) {
    bool all_conditions = true;
    int flip_index = -1;
    bool set = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < BITLEN; i++) {
        /*a0 and a1 represent the state of A
          11 is FLIP, 10 is ON, 01 is OFF, and 00 is NONE */
        bool A = (*state)[i];
        bool a1 = (*gate)[i*2];
        bool a0 = (*gate)[(i*2)+1];

        if (a1&&a0) {
            flip_index = i;
            set = true;
        }

        //NONE or FLIP have no condition to meet
        //ON means A must be true
        //OFF means A must be false
        //this simplifies to the below if statement
        if (!((!a0&&!a1) || (!A&&a1) || (A&&a0))) {
            all_conditions = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    //if all conditions are met flip the bit with state FLIP
    //check set flag in case gate is not valid
    if (all_conditions && set)
        state->flip(flip_index);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your gate representation:

```
struct GATE {
    std::bitset<BITLEN> required_on;
    std::bitset<BITLEN> required_off;
    std::bitset<BITLEN> flip;
};
```

And then you can implement operation very efficiently with bit operations:

```
void toffoli(const GATE* gate, INPUT* state) {
    if((*state & (gate->required_on | gate->required_off)) == gate->required_on)
        *state ^= gate->flip;
    }
}
```

Comment: compiling with gcc version 4.8.4 and c++11 gives errors saying bitwise operators are not defined for bitset.

Comment: Also, should `*state ^= flip;` be `*state ^= gate->flip;`

Comment: After a little research, it would appear an extra set of parenthesis is needed around the bitwise &'s or the compiler gets confused about what the & should be bound to.

Comment: Corrected, I also changed it to use only one comparison, rather than two.